# Transformar valor obtenido de input radio

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, nodejs, base-de-datos

tengo un cuestionario de inputs radio dónde el usuario tiene que seleccionar una opción númerica 1,2,3,4 o 5, de cada pregunta formulada.
La opción que seleccione se registra igual en base de datos, es decir, si el usuario selecciona de una pregunta la opción 1 se registra el valor 1.
El problema es que tengo que hacer transformaciones con los valores iniciales, si el usuario marca la opción 1 se debe registrar aparte en base de datos el valor 5 (1=5, 2=4, 3=3, 4=2, 5=1). Posteriormente, cuando estén las transformaciones calculadas tengo que realizar operaciones matemáticas. A continuación dejo el código para que les sea de más utilidad.

```
    function resultadosCuestionario() {
        if (validar()) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'XXXXXXXX',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            PR1: document.querySelector('input[name="preg1"]:checked').value,
            PR2: document.querySelector('input[name="preg2"]:checked').value,
            PR3: document.querySelector('input[name="preg3"]:checked').value,
            PR4: document.querySelector('input[name="preg4"]:checked').value,
            PR5: document.querySelector('input[name="preg5"]:checked').value
        },
        success: function (respuesta) {
                console.log(respuesta.message)
                if (respuesta.message.affectedRows > 0) {
                     console.log("Los datos se han enviado correctamente")
                     window.location.href = "#";
                } else {
                    console.log("Faltan datos por introducir")
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("No es posible completar la operación");
            }
                });
            }
        }
        
</script>

<div id="cuestionario" class="radios">
            <div class="enunciado">
                <label>1.Pregunta del cuestionario. </label>
       <div class="respuestas">
            <input type="radio" name="preg1" value="1"/>1 
            <input type="radio" name="preg1" value="2"/>2 
            <input type="radio" name="preg1" value="3"/>3 
            <input type="radio" name="preg1" value="4"/>4 
            <input type="radio" name="preg1" value="5"/>5 
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
            <div class="enunciado">
                <label>2. Segunda pregunta cuesitonario.</label>
            <div class="respuestas">
            <input type="radio" name="preg2" value="1"/>1 
            <input type="radio" name="preg2" value="2"/>2 
            <input type="radio" name="preg2" value="3"/>3 
            <input type="radio" name="preg2" value="4"/>4 
            <input type="radio" name="preg2" value="5"/>5 
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
```

Desconozco como puedo generar otra función dónde se haga dicha transformación, es decir, cuando en una pregunta se seleccione la opción 1 se tendría que guardar el valor 1 en un campo y el valor 5 en otro campo. He estado practicando pero no me funciona ningún código:

```
    var num = parseFloat(input.value);
    if (num == 1) {
        num == 5;
      } else if (num == 2){
        num == 4;
      } else if (num == 3){
        num == 3;
      } else if (num == 4){
        num == 2;
      } else if (num == 5){
        num == 1;
      }
      }

function valorInverso (){
    if  (PR1 == '1'){
        PR1X == '5';
    } else if (PR1 == '2'){
        PR1X == '4';
    }else if (PR1 == '3'){
        PR1X == '3';
    } else if (PR1 == '2'){
        PR1X == '4';
    } else if (PR1 == '1'){
        PR1X == '5';
    } 

function valorInverso (){
if (PR1[1] == 1) {PR1X[1] = PR1[1];PR1X[1] = 5;}
if (PR1[1] == 2) {PR1X[1] = PR1[1];PR1X[1] = 4;}
if (PR1[1] == 3) {PR1X[1] = PR1[1];PR1X[1] = 3;}
if (PR1[1] == 4) {PR1X[1] = PR1[1];PR1X[1] = 2;}
if (PR1[1] == 5) {PR1X[1] = PR1[1];PR1X[1] = 1;}
```

Muchas gracias por la atención.

Comment: ¿Y no te vale con poner en `value` el número que deseas? Ejemplo: `<input type="radio" name="preg1" value="5"/>1` `<input ... value="4"/>2`, etc.

Comment: Es que tengo que guardar de cada uno dos valores, es decir, <input type="radio" name="preg1" value="1"/>1 (si selecciona ésta, guarda valor 1, pero también tendría que guardar en otro campo el valor 5).

Answer (score 4):

Si siempre es la transformación 1=5, 2=4, 3=3, 4=2, y 5=1, entonces una función como esta funcionaría:

```
function transformarValor(valorOriginal) {
    return 6 - valorOriginal;
}
```

Te recomendaría guardar los resultados en un objeto, para usarlo luego para lo que quieras:

```js
function transformarValor(valorOriginal) {
  return 6 - valorOriginal;
}

function obtenerValores(name) {
  const original = document.querySelector(`input[name="${name}"]:checked`).value
  return {
    original,
    transformado: transformarValor(original),
  };
}

function cambioValor(event) {
  const name = event.target.name;
  const valores = obtenerValores(name);
  console.log(`${name} (${valores.original}) -> ${valores.transformado}`);
}

document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]')
  .forEach(elemento => elemento.addEventListener('change', cambioValor));
```

```html
<div id="cuestionario" class="radios">
  <div class="enunciado">
    <label>1.Pregunta del cuestionario. </label>
    <div class="respuestas">
      <input type="radio" name="preg1" value="1" checked/>1 
      <input type="radio" name="preg1" value="2"/>2 
      <input type="radio" name="preg1" value="3"/>3 
      <input type="radio" name="preg1" value="4"/>4 
      <input type="radio" name="preg1" value="5"/>5 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="enunciado">
    <label>2. Segunda pregunta cuesitonario.</label>
    <div class="respuestas">
      <input type="radio" name="preg2" value="1" checked/>1 
      <input type="radio" name="preg2" value="2"/>2 
      <input type="radio" name="preg2" value="3"/>3 
      <input type="radio" name="preg2" value="4"/>4 
      <input type="radio" name="preg2" value="5"/>5 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```